# Recover Table data in SQL Server without having DB backup

Tags: sql-server, recovery

I wanted to modified (deleting 4-5 columns via table design mode) the table structure. but by mistakenly I have deleted from Live database. I don't have latest back of the live database.

Can I get the data (200 rows) which get deleted? Help appreciated.

Comment: Learn to take **backups** before doing stuff like that!!

Answer (score 1):

Theres no good easy way to do this if you dont have a backup. This thread details your options:

[Rollback transaction using transaction log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065531/rollback-transaction-using-transaction-log)

Basically if the database is not in full logging mode, youre likely out of luck.

Answer (score -1):

try this..

`BEGIN 
TRAN
 TRUNCATE TABLE table name 
ROLLBACK 
SELECT * FROM table name` 
- See more at: http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/rollback-truncate-operation-without-backups/#sthash.CRIRGE9b.dpuf

Comment: That command will not restore the data that he has lost by dropping columns. I would not recommend running it because you could do even more damage for no reason. However, from your link, ApexSQL Recover says it can restore the data lost through dropped columns.